# Организация БД

Tags: база-данных, sql, mysql

Доброго дня всем!

Имеется набор товаров. У каждого товара есть некоторые свойства. 
Свойства могут быть 
 - групповыми(длина,ширина,высота), одиночными (вес, цвет)
 - списковыми(тот же цвет: есть несколько четко заданных вариантов расцветки), строковыми(надпись сбоку, например), числовыми (тот же вес).
 - общими для всей группы товаров(длина, ширина, высота), уникальными для конкретного товара(какая-то особенность)

У некоторых числовых свойств есть единицы измерения, например, метр, миллиметр, кг и так далее.
У этих единиц измерения есть возможные написания, в зависимости от числительного
1 минута, 2 минуты, 5 минут, а так же сокращенное написание: мин.

В итоге, у меня получается довольно громоздкая система таблиц:

```
catalog_groups
id, parent_id, path, title

catalog_items
id, group_id, title

catalog_group_parameters
id, id_group, type, value

catalog_parameters
parameter_id, item_id, value

catalog_list
list_id, id, value

catalog...
```

ну и так далее, все равно никто читать не будет.

Проблемы, которые не удалось решить:
Если есть общие величины, вроде высоты, которые распространяются на все-все, как их объединить в одну? При этом, скажем, цвет - это разные параметры, так как списки цветов разные для групп.

Получается, иногда в значении value для параметра у меня именно значение, а иногда - идентификатор списка.

В общем, как умные дяди и тети это организовывают?

Comment: Вопрос - как планируется добавлять обычные и особенно уникальные свойства? 

С обычными более-менее понятно, админка, карточка товара, список полей под основной инфой etc. А уникальные?

*ЗЫ: я не исчез, я улетел, но обещал вернуться ;)*

Comment: Как в друпале: админка, карточка товара, добавить [дополнительное/особенное/нестандартное] свойство. Появляется окошечко, куда пишем это свойство и окошечко, куда пишем имя свойства.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще таблица видов свойств должна быть одна. На все группы. Т.е. цвет и высота - это два свойства, а не 2*количество групп. При этом у товаров будут те свойства, которые есть (пусть даже набор свойств у разных товаров одной группы будет отличаться).

Далее для каждой группы должна быть развязочная таблица, что в этой группе есть такие-то свойства (т.е. `group_id`, `parameter_id`), по которым можно фильтровать. При этом значения для фильтра берутся `distinct`'ом (для диапазонов соответственно min/max) по значениям этого свойства для товаров в данной группе, т.е. список значений хранить не нужно, соответственно и разделять свойство "цвет" для разных групп нет смысла, лишние цвета в фильтр не попадут.

Тогда проблемы с идентификаторами списков возникнуть не должно...

**N.B.** Свойства делятся на:

- булевы (в плане выбора виджета - чекбокс, понятно что можно и радио и селект сделать на два элемента).
- числовые или дата (сравнение больше, меньше, диапазон)
- строковые (совпадение по строке, по подстроке)
- лукап (одно значение из списка возможных значений)
- множественный лукап (когда можно выбрать несколько значений: красные или синие)
- более сложные варианты типа по подстроке множественного лукапа (синие: "темно-синие", "светло-синие", "синие в белую полоску") или поиск по древовидному справочнике - в детях. зависит от причудливости справочников.

Ну и для каждого варианта строится свой виджет в фильтре.

ЗЫ Надеюсь правильно понял проблему.

Comment: Без списков обойтись не получится: одно и то же значение пользователь может записать по-разному, если дать возможность заполнять произвольно: 
материал
чугун, чугуний, из чугуна, чугунная(ый), черное железо,... 
Русский язык велик и мопед. =(
_____________________
Увы, проблема понята не совсем верно, хотя идея создать отдельную таблицу для свойств - это как раз то, о чем я спрашивал. То что нужно.
Я же спрашивал много шире: об организации не только этих групп, но и всех связок. 


булевы - это список из двух элементов. Отдельный тип ему не нужен.

P.S. размер коммента ограничен

Comment: Не, ну понятно, что значения изначально могут заноситься в отдельный справочник, но он все равно общий. От групп и товаров не зависит. Скажем в цвета можно забить [таблицу](http://vvz.nw.ru/Lessons/HTML_Colors/HTMLcolors_HSB.htm) в справочник, а использоваться будут красный и черный только. Значения для конкретного свойства в конкретной группе определяется все равно значениями имеющимися у товаров в данной группе, поэтому distinct.  
По поводу единиц измерения и их написания. С такой причудой не сталкивался, но в конечном итоге просто добавляется одно поле в выборке, а написание - в скрипте..

Comment: > Получается, иногда в значении value для параметра у меня именно значение, а иногда - идентификатор списка.

Ну это вообще не проблема. Если взять фильтр, то от вас зависит как пользователь будет вводить цвет - по буквам (см. более сложный вариант в списке видов в ответе) или выбирать из возможных цветов.  
В первом случае в запрос просто добавится join со справочником и сравнение будет с полем из справочника. Во втором случае id'шники просто будут и все: value in (1,25,3).

ЗЫ Про булевы уточнил.

Comment: я задавал похожий вопрос :), но что-то все равно непонятно, как это один параметр с разными значениями (цвет) фильтровать дистинком для разных групп, если там разные допустимые цвета? а также: нужно ли создавать доп таблицы под разные типы параметров?

Comment: @majatu примерно так:

    select distinct pv.value
    from products p
    join propertyvalues pv on p.id=pv.product_id and pv.prop_id=42
    where p.group_id = 100

по поводу разных таблиц, то допустимо поступать и так и так. Одна таблица проще в построении запросов, несколько таблиц - отсуствие приведения типов. Замеров не делал, что быстрее врать не буду.

Answer (score 3):

Попробую накидать примерную структуру. Что-то подобное делал, "но есть нюанс".

Таблицы:

```
1. fields [ field_id, name, type(group/bool/int/list/color), <...>, is_multiple(0/1)]
2. values [ product_id, field_id, value ]
3. groups [ group_id, cat_id, name, <...> ]
4. fields_link [ field_id, link_id, link_to(группа, поле-группа, товар)]
```

Соотв-но наши действия:

```
1. Создание категории
2. Создание группы полей для категории
  2.1. При создании подкатегории клонируем группу с прилинкованными полями 
  2.2. Добавление в эту группу существующих полей и/или создание новых
    2.2.1 для групповых свойств создаем группу-поле и линкуем их туда
3. Создание товара
  3.1. Заполнение полей
  3.2. Создание уникальных (при таком раскладе, если поле создано где-то еще, можно привязать из общего списка)
4. Вывод
```

Для вывода получаем список полей (вроде должно быть прозрачно, линки по группа/категория, подгруппа/группа, поле/товар), следом получаем все значения (банальным **`SELECT * FROM values WHERE product_id={$product->id}`**, потом в скрипте дописываем полям значение, сортируем, добавляем окончания, форматируем etc). Множественные, кстати, учтены - их просто будет несколько в таблице values.

Вопросы в каменты)

Comment: 4я таблица непонятна. можно поподробнее по полям в частности link_id и link_to?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, `link_to` - тип связи, `link_id` - идентификатор записи. Например, 

    WHERE link_to='product' AND link_id=15

это уникальные поля (привязанные к продукту с product_id=15), 

    WHERE link_to='group' AND link_id=2

это поля для категории (т.е. для группы с group_id=2)

и т.д. Для поля-группы надо будет джойнить таблицу с полями еще раз и что-то вроде

    WHERE l.link_to='groupfield' AND l.link_id=f2.field_id

Мне, если честно, лень сейчас составлять запрос выборки всех полей, ибо путаюсь в типах джойнов без мануала)

Comment: @Sh4dow, спасибо, просто необходимости в таких связях не испытывал, поэтому не догонял.